# Shortening the representation of a string by adding the number of consecutive characters

Tags: java, string

Given a random character string not including (0-9), I need to shorten the representation of that string by adding the number of consecutive characters. For e.g: ggee will result in g2e2 being displayed.

I managed to implement the program and tested it (works correctly) through various inputs. I have run into the issue where I cannot seem to understand how the character "e" is displayed given the input above.

I have traced my code multiple times but I don't see when/how "e" is displayed when "i" is 2/3.

```
String input = new String("ggee");
char position = input.charAt(0);
int accumulator = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    // Correction. Was boolean lastIndexString = input.charAt(i) == (input.charAt(input.length() - 1));
    boolean lastIndexString = i == (input.length() - 1); 
    if (position == input.charAt(i))
    {
        accumulator++;
        if (lastIndexOfString)
            System.out.print(accumulator); // In my mind, I should be printing 
                                           // (input.charAt(i) + "" + accumulator); here
    }
    else //(position != input.charAt(i))
    {
        if (accumulator > 1)
        {
            System.out.print(position + "" + accumulator);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(position + "");
        }
        position = input.charAt(i);
        accumulator = 1;

        if (lastIndexOfString)
           System.out.print(input.charAt(i)); // This is always printing when 
                                              //  I am at the last index of my string, 
                                              //  even ignoring my condition of 
                                              //  (position == input.charAt(i))
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I need to **shorten** ... e.g: `ggee` will result in `g2e2` being displayed"* --- That is the same length, i.e. **not shorter**.

Comment: I understand but I gave this example for simplicity. If i have for eg: ggggee, this will result in g4e2.

Comment: In Java 9+, the following will do it: `System.out.print(Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(input).replaceAll(r -> r.group(1) + r.group().length()));`. --- E.g. input `"ggggeecaaaaaaaaaaaa"` prints `g4e2ca12`

Comment: Thank you so much for this eye opening solution. I will use this in the future. However, I still want to make my solution work.

Comment: You need to entirely re-think what you're trying to do. E.g. `lastIndexOfString` is entirely wrong, because what does comparing current character with last character signify? *Nothing!* --- Think of input `"aabbbaaabbaaaa"`. Why would the fact that first character is same as last character matter? Why would the fact that any of the 3 middle `a` characters is same as last character matter? ---  Take a step back, re-think, and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what i did that either. If you could answer to the post I will give you the check mark for the answer.

Comment: Observation: I think this is a case where [Rubber Duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) would work better than tracing using debugger, etc.

Comment: I actually traced my code by hand to make sure. I think i wasn't paying attention enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 9+, using regular expression to find consecutive characters, the following will do it:

```
static String shorten(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(input)
            .replaceAll(r -> r.group(1) + r.group().length());
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(shorten("ggggeecaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
System.out.println(shorten("ggggee"));
```

*Output*

```
g4e2ca12
g4e268
```

However, as you can see, that code doesn't work if input string contains Unicode characters from the supplemental planes, such as Emoji characters.

Small modification will fix that:

```
static String shorten(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(input)
            .replaceAll(r -> r.group(1) + r.group().codePointCount(0, r.group().length()));
}
```

Or:

```
static String shorten(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(input)
            .replaceAll(r -> r.group(1) + input.codePointCount(r.start(), r.end()));
}
```

*Output*

```
g4e2ca12
g4e234
```

Comment: Also, for a simpler logic better avoid using already built in methods to resolve. As this may not be standard as well. For such a high reputation din expect this

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja 1) For *simpler* logic, we should definitely be using already built in methods, rather than rewriting that already written logic. That makes *our* code, i.e. the new code we're writing, much simpler. --- 2) *"this may not be standard"* What may not be standard? This answer uses only standard Java APIs. I did specify up front that it requires Java 9+. Since question didn't specify a restriction on Java version, this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I said for basic problems importing an extra package with its methods called seems like solving without logic with an overhead of import. These type of problems doesnt relate to any real enterprise problem but a test problem to test the basic logic. The OP wont get an idea basically to resolve it in a actual way.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja *"seems like solving without logic"* Use the tools available to you *is* solving *with* logic. Not using the tools to available would be illogical. --- *"with an overhead of import"* There is no overhead to imports. --- *"wont get an idea basically to resolve it in a actual way"* This code is an "actual" way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want each char with no of  repeats.

```
*******************************************************************************/

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="ggggggeee";
        StringBuilder s1=new 
         StringBuilder("") ;
           ;




       for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
      {
     int count=0,j;
        for( j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
        {
       if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j))
       count++;
       else 
         {
             break;}
        } 
        i=j-1;
     s1=s1.append(s.charAt(i)+""+(count+1));


       } 

       System.out.print(s1);



}}
```

Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: So very flawed. Doesn't compile (**18** errors). Even if compilation errors are fixed, the result is wrong.

Comment: An *idea* of an **incorrect result** is not really useful.

Comment: Edited. Check now,

Comment: `c1`? The goal was to **shorten** the string, not make it longer.

Comment: dont manipulate now as that can also be taken into account by if count>1 else..Higher reputation doesnt mean you should avoid seeing the logic itself better before giving a negative vote should have stated in comment

Comment: *"Higher reputation doesnt mean you should avoid seeing the logic itself better"* Huh? I can see the logic, but that doesn't mean that **everybody else** reading this answer might be able to quickly see that. --- *"before giving a negative vote"* I have not given this answer (version 2) a negative vote. The first version got negative vote because it was so very flawed, as I already said in the first comment. --- *"should have stated in comment"* What should I have stated in a comment that I haven't already stated?

Comment: Well, i would not confess anymore. I can see a negative vote still. This makes it clear high reputation vs a basic rep matters here